# Plot and subplot

Tags: python, plot, subplot

I want to plot 3 similar data in one figure, so I tried this code :

```
f1 = open('C:/data/EF2011S.txt', 'r') 
f2 = open('C:/data/EF2012S.txt', 'r') 
f3 = open('C:/data/EF2013S.txt', 'r')
```

## get values from the 1st to the 365th line

```
x1_start, x1_end = 1, 365 
y1_start, y1_end = 1, 365 # 
y11_start, y11_end = 1, 365 #
```

## get values from the 1st to the 366th line

```
x2_start, x2_end = 1, 366    
y2_start, y2_end = 1, 3 line
y21_start, y21_end = 1, 366
```

## get values from the 1st to the 313th line

```
x3_start, x3_end = 1, 313 
y3_start, y3_end = 1, 313 
y31_start, y31_end = 1, 313 


x1 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2011S.txt', usecols=(0))
y1 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2011S.txt', usecols=(5))
y11 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2011S.txt', usecols=(10))

x2 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2012S.txt', usecols=(0))
y2 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2012S.txt', usecols=(5))
y21 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2012S.txt', usecols=(10))

x3 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2013S.txt', usecols=(0))
y3 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2013S.txt', usecols=(5))
y31 = np.genfromtxt('C:/data/EF2013S.txt', usecols=(10))

x1 = x1[x1_start - 1:x1_end]
y1 = y1[y1_start - 1:y1_end]
y11 = y11[y11_start - 1:y11_end]

x2 = x2[x2_start - 1:x2_end]
y2 = y2[y2_start - 1:y2_end]
y21 = y21[y21_start - 1:y21_end]

x3 = x3[x3_start - 1:x3_end]
y3 = y3[y3_start - 1:y3_end]
y31 = y31[y31_start - 1:y31_end]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)

ax1.set_title(" ")    
ax1.set_xlabel(' ')
ax1.set_ylabel(' ')

ax1.plot(x1,y1,y11, c='r', label='the data')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)

ax2.set_title(" ")    
ax2.set_xlabel(' ')
ax2.set_ylabel(' ')

ax2.plot(x2,y2,y21, c='b', label='the data')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)

ax3.set_title(" ")    
ax3.set_xlabel(' ')
ax3.set_ylabel(' ')

ax3.plot(x3,y3,y31, c='g', label='the data')


leg1 = ax1.legend()
leg2 = ax2.legend()
leg3 = ax3.legend()

plt.show()
```

But I got error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
line 540, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
File "C:/DATA2012/Plot1.py", line 58, in <module>
ax1.plot(x1,y1,y11, c='r', label='the data')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4137, in plot
for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 279, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError('third arg must be a format string')
    ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 0):

Every 'y-value' argument, must be matched with a 'x-value' argument. Try

```
ax1.plot(x1,y1,x1,y11 ...)
```

Comment: I tried, but only frame of figure was plotted. Why the data can not be load?

Comment: Any errors? Have you checked that your data is in the variables correctly? It should be working now. Tested it myself with some dummy data.

Comment: No error, but only frame was plotted. Data consist of 11 columns. The first column is date, and others are scientific data. I only want plot the 5th and 10th column.

Comment: Then i'm sorry, but i don't know what the problem is now.

Comment: figure didn't show plot of data. Only frame/window of figure was shown